# Transition The Size of a Container When jQuery Adds Children

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I'm looking for a way to animate the increase of an element's (border) size when jQuery either adds a child or shows one that was hidden, either or. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr8vjtyq/) likely explains this better. Instead of the divider instantly transforming to the new size when the label is clicked displaying the second label, is there a way to transform it slowly? I've tried every combination of CSS and JS I could think of and find on Stack to no avail. Help appreciated!

```js
function load() {
  $("#example").hide();
  $("label").click(function() {
    $("#example").fadeIn();
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload=load()>
  <div>
    <label>Shown</label>
    <label id=example>Addition</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you can add timing to the `fadeIn(3000)` => the `3000` = `3 seconds`  however, the border will show before the fadeIn timing fades the element into view. Are you looking to have the actual border fadeIn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.slideToggle()` - this will slide the bottom border down as the parent div increases in size.

```
$("#example").slideToggle();
```

This will also bring the bottom border up in a smooth transition when hiding.

---

```js
function load() {
        $("#example").hide();
    $("label").click(function() {
            $("#example").slideToggle();
    })
}
```

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload=load()>
  <div>
      <label>Shown</label>
      <label id=example>Addition</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is perfect! "Sliding" the bottom border down was an option in my head too but I doubted there was a simple way to do so! +1!

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you are looking to delay the showing of the actual element and its properties *(border)*, you can add a `setTimeout()` function to the JS code that will delay for a given amount of time as set in your timeout function, then it will run the built in `fadeIn` jQuery function.

You could add a CSS ***animation*** and use ***@keyframes*** to make the animations ***opacity*** fade in, however this will be constrained to certain properties in CSS only.

Let me know if this was not what you were looking to achieve. I used the example code you linked to in the JSFiddle.

```js
function delayFade(time) {
  setTimeout(() => $("#example").fadeIn(), time);
}

function load() {
  $("#example").hide();
  $("label").click(() => delayFade(1500));
}
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload=load()>
  <div>
    <label>Shown</label>
    <label id=example>Addition</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I may have phrased that poorly. The first JSFiddle was an **extremely** watered-down version of my project. Take a look at this slightly updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amt752jy/). I'm looking for the new blue/div expansion to fade in alongside the text and not instantly appear on the screen. Ideas?